# How to accumulate arrays of data efficiently in C

Tags: c, arrays, database, sse, inline-assembly

The problem is that I have a huge matrix A, and given an (quite large) integer array, for example, say my matrix is:
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
 ...............]

and the integer array is [0, 2, 4]

Then the desired answer is [6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6] by accumulating [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]

This is a simple problem, but a naive C implementation seems to be very slow. This is especially the case when accumulating a lot of rows.

manually loop_unrolling doesn't seem to help. I am not familiar with inline assembly, any suggestions? I am wondering if there is a known library for such operations as well.

Below is my current implementation:

```
void accumulateRows(int* js, int num_j, Dtype* B, int nrow, int ncol, int incRowB, Dtype* buffer){

int i = 0;
int num_accumulated_rows = (num_j / 8) * 8;
int remaining_rows = num_j - num_accumulated_rows;

// unrolling factor of 8, each time, accumulate 8 rows  
for(; i < num_accumulated_rows; i+=8){
    int r1 = js[i];
    int r2 = js[i+1];
    int r3 = js[i+2];
    int r4 = js[i+3];
    int r5 = js[i+4];
    int r6 = js[i+5];
    int r7 = js[i+6];
    int r8 = js[i+7];
    register Dtype* B1_row = &B[r1*incRowB];
    register Dtype* B2_row = &B[r2*incRowB];
    register Dtype* B3_row = &B[r3*incRowB];
    register Dtype* B4_row = &B[r4*incRowB];
    register Dtype* B5_row = &B[r5*incRowB];
    register Dtype* B6_row = &B[r6*incRowB];
    register Dtype* B7_row = &B[r7*incRowB];
    register Dtype* B8_row = &B[r8*incRowB];
    for(int j = 0; j < ncol; j+=1){
        register Dtype temp = B1_row[j] + B2_row[j] + B3_row[j] + B4_row[j];
        temp += B5_row[j] + B6_row[j] + B7_row[j] + B8_row[j];
        buffer[j] += temp;
    }
}

// left_over from the loop unrolling
for(; i < remaining_rows; i++){
    int r = js[i];
    Dtype* B_row = &B[r*incRowB];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        buffer[i] += B_row[i];
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT**
I think this accumulation is very common in database, for example when we want to make a query about the total sales made in any Monday, Tueday, etc.

I know gcc supports Intel SSE, and I am looking to learn how to apply that to this problem, since this is very much SIMD

Comment: Are you going to share your "slow naive C implementation"?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean when you say you want the *rows of `A` into a single buffer*. Could you give an example?

Comment: Is that amount of redundancy common or expected in your matrix?  If so, just sum the integer array to `6` and *then* broadcast the result to `6,6,6,6,...`.  If it's not, your C code looks like it might auto-vectorize reasonably well.  As long as you're loading contiguous data, you should be fine.  A gather is slow, but consecutive indices of an array can be loaded efficiently.

Comment: There is no 2D array (aka matrix) in your code.

Comment: @PeterCordes no, there is no redundancy, it was just an easy example. The 2D matrix is flattened to a 1D, as typically down in C

Comment: @Olaf According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Size), matrices can have a size of 1, and it was quite clear from the question that the 2d version was flattened to a 1d version. Lay off on the nitpicking and focus on the question.

Comment: @MillieSmith: Thank your for informing me how to read C code. I really have no idea what I would do without your always welcome comments. Said that: OP clearly wants to use a 2D array semantically. Thus the question is, why obfuscating his code using a 1D array (which is called in mathematics a "vector" normally) and doing the indexing manually. Why not just leaving that to the compiler. That would make the code clearer and less error-prone. Oh, and that will not be less efficient. It actually is very well possible the compiler will detect that design-pattern and optimize that code better.

Comment: @Olaf That was a much more useful comment than your first one.

Comment: in general, loop unrolling is something you tell the compiler to perform, usually via a pragma, not something you do in the source code.

Comment: just what is a `Dtype`?

Comment: it seems to me that the list of parameters to the function should be `int numRows, int numCols,  int BaseArray[][ numCols ],  int numSelectRows, int *whichRows[ numSelectRows ], int* resultArray[ numCols ] )`   Which, amongst other things, would use meaningful names

Comment: you might want to look at the `#pragma GCC ivdep` for having the compiler unroll loops

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to implement the function, along with a few suggestions about further speedups

```
#include <stdlib.h> // size_t

typedef int Dtype;

// Note:
// following function assumes a 'contract' with the caller
//    that no entry in 'whichRows[]'
//    is larger than (number of rows in 'baseArray[][]' -1)

void accumulateRows(
    // describe source 2d array
    /* size_t numRows */ size_t numCols, Dtype BaseArray[][ numCols ],

    // describe row selector array
    size_t numSelectRows, size_t whichRows[ numSelectRows ],

    // describe result array
    Dtype resultArray[ numCols ] )
{
    size_t colIndex;
    size_t selectorIndex;

    // initialize resultArray to all 0
    for( colIndex = 0; colIndex < numCols; colIndex++ )
    {
        resultArray[colIndex] = 0;
    }

    // accumulate totals for each column of selected rows
    for( selectorIndex = 0; selectorIndex < numSelectRows; selectorIndex++ )
    {
        for( colIndex = 0; colIndex < numCols; colIndex++ )
        {
            resultArray[colIndex] += BaseArray[ whichRows[selectorIndex] ][colIndex];
        } // end for each column
    } // end for each selected row
}

#if 0
// you might want to unroll the "initialize resultArray" loop
//    by replacing the loop with
    resultArray[0] = 0;
    resultArray[1] = 0;
    resultArray[2] = 0;
    resultArray[3] = 0;
    resultArray[4] = 0;
    resultArray[5] = 0;
    resultArray[6] = 0;
    resultArray[7] = 0;
// however, that puts a constraint on the number of columns always being 8
#endif

#if 0
// you might want to unroll the 'sum of columns' loop by replacing the loop with
    resultArray[0] += BaseArray[ whichRows[selectorIndex] ][0];
    resultArray[1] += BaseArray[ whichRows[selectorIndex] ][1];
    resultArray[2] += BaseArray[ whichRows[selectorIndex] ][2];
    resultArray[3] += BaseArray[ whichRows[selectorIndex] ][3];
    resultArray[4] += BaseArray[ whichRows[selectorIndex] ][4];
    resultArray[5] += BaseArray[ whichRows[selectorIndex] ][5];
    resultArray[6] += BaseArray[ whichRows[selectorIndex] ][6];
    resultArray[7] += BaseArray[ whichRows[selectorIndex] ][7];
// however, that puts a constraint on the number of columns always being 8
#endif

#if 0
// on Texas Instrument DSPs ,
//    could use a #pragma to unroll the loop
//    or (better)
//    make use of the built-in loop table
//    to massively speed up the execution of the loop(s)
#endif
```